# Command to request EXE for Windows firewall name?

Tags: windows-7, windows-firewall

On Windows 7, I can use the following command to get information about a firewall rule:

```
netsh advfirewall show rule name=foobarTCP
```

yields:

```
Rule Name:                            foobarTCP
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Enabled:                              Yes
Direction:                            In
Profiles:                             Domain,Private,Public
Grouping:                             
LocalIP:                              Any
RemoteIP:                             Any
Protocol:                             TCP
LocalPort:                            Any
RemotePort:                           Any
Edge traversal:                       No
Action:                               Allow
```

But I would like to know the specific EXE identified with that rule. I can see this info in *Control Panel -> Windows Firewall -> Advanced Settings -> Inbound Rules*. e.g. that foobarTCP is `c:\ProgramData\MyCompany\foobar.exe`

How can I get the EXE path via `netsh` (or another command line tool?). Please note that installing PowerShell is not an option for me.

Answer (score 1):

After some research, I discovered this (note *verbose*):

```
netsh advfirewall show rule name=foobarTCP verbose
```